# can`t pass command line args using lerna

Tags: javascript, yarnpkg, lerna

I try run the script from the root but got the error:

`ERR! lerna Unknown argument: d`

the command from root package.json:

`"start:scripts:api-football:start:collectDayMatches:dev": "lerna run start:collectDayMatches:dev --stream"`

try run `yarn start:scripts:api-football:start:collectDayMatches:dev -- -d 2002-02-02`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems you are trying to pass command arguments to the npm script of each package.

For example:

`packages/pkg-a/package.json`:

```json
"scripts": {
  "start:collectDayMatches:dev": "ls"
}
```

root `package.json`:

```json
"scripts": {
  "start:scripts:api-football:start:collectDayMatches:dev": "lerna run start:collectDayMatches:dev --stream"
}
```

Let's pass the `-a` option to the `ls` command.

You should run the npm script with three double-dash (`--`) like this:

```
[main] ⚡  yarn start:scripts:api-football:start:collectDayMatches:dev -- -- -- -a
yarn run v1.22.10
warning From Yarn 1.0 onwards, scripts don't require "--" for options to be forwarded. In a future version, any explicit "--" will be forwarded as-is to the scripts.
$ lerna run start:collectDayMatches:dev --stream -- -- -a
lerna notice cli v3.22.1
lerna info Executing command in 1 package: "npm run start:collectDayMatches:dev -- -a"
pkg-a: > pkg-a@1.0.0 start:collectDayMatches:dev /Users/dulin/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/lerna-codelab/packages/pkg-a
pkg-a: > ls "-a"
pkg-a: .
pkg-a: ..
pkg-a: app.js
pkg-a: app.test.js
pkg-a: docs
pkg-a: jest.config.js
pkg-a: node_modules
pkg-a: package-lock.json
pkg-a: package.json
lerna success run Ran npm script 'start:collectDayMatches:dev' in 1 package in 0.2s:
lerna success - pkg-a
✨  Done in 0.60s.
```

As you can see, the final command is `ls "-a"`.

Answer (score 2):

**Solution**

Add `-- -- --` between the lerna command and the argument you want passed in.

As per the question example...

For the command:

```
yarn start:collectDayMatches:dev
```

add the `-- -- --` syntax:

```
yarn start:collectDayMatches:dev -- -- -- d
```

(This is the same solution as https://stackoverflow.com/a/66060685/4930577, but simplified)